# Can the derivative of a function that involves $\sqrt{x}$ have 2 answers?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Textbook question- Calculate the gradient of the tangent where $x=1$ for:
$f(x)=3x^3+x\sqrt{x}$.

My working- Okay here i used the power rule to determine the derivative, and i got:$f'(x)=9x^2+\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}$.

From my equation, $f'(1)=\frac{21}{2}$.But my textbook answer gave:$f'(1)=\frac{15}{2}$.

Which means that the textbook's equation is $f'(x)=9x^2-\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}$. It somehow turned into minus which i could not understand.

**So my question is can the $\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}$ be ± (plus or minus)?**
Thanks.

Comment: You are right. Your textbook is wrong.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos so it is impossible to get plus or minus in all situations?

Comment: @FredWeasley Yes, it is. The $\pm$ thing is a huge, huge common misconception (by no fault of students). The expression $x=\pm a$ isn't an equality *at all*. It's actually an abbreviation of $x=a \lor x=-a$. It's not possible for $x$ to be equal to two different things. It's either one or the other, and by convention the square root is taken to be positive, unless otherwise stated, and I've never seen it stated otherwise.

Comment: You are correct! $f'(1)=\frac{15}{2}$ if $f(x)=3x^3-x\sqrt{x}$. It's just a typo.

Comment: Either there is a typo in the book, or the question was stated differently.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt x$ denotes the positive square root of $x$ so $x \sqrt x$ would be $x^{1.5}$. Then performing the derivative should give you the answer YOU got i.e. $\frac{21}{2}$.

It so happens that $g(x) = 3x^3 \color{red}{-} x \sqrt x $ and $h(x) = 3x^3 + x\sqrt{x}$ with the square root being the negative one, have the same derivative at $1$ i.e. $\frac{15}{2}$.

Therefore, while you are thinking that this is a case of negative square root over positive, I am not sure that is the case : in fact, I think that the textbook meant $g$ in place of $f$ (I have never seen instances of the "negative square root" beyond basic set-function theory).

The $\frac{3}{2} \sqrt x$ is then very much a plus, but the function $f$ should have a $-$ before $x \sqrt x$, not $+$, to give the textbook answer.